# Can't add relative quantities, assembly error

Tags: assembly, x86

so for a project i need to program a game in 80386 (32-bit processor).

To draw a pixel we got this example code from the teacher:

-first set the video mode:
MOV ah, 00h
MOV al, 13h
INT 10h

-drawing the pixel:

```
MOV ESI, 0A0000H ; frame buffer address

MOV EDI, 320 * 2 + 10; add the appropriate offset
MOV AL, 10 ; index in the colour palette
MOV [EDI], AL ; change pixel at column 10 of row 2
```

This code works perfectly, but in my game code i want to add in the data the x and y positions of the 'player'

xpos dw 10
ypos dw 2

when i try to acces those variables i get the error "Can't add relative quantities"

i've tried:

```
MOV ESI, 0A0000H ; frame buffer address
MOV EDI, 320 * offset yPosChar + offset xPosChar; add the appropriate offset
MOV AL, 10 ; index in the colour palette
MOV [EDI], AL ; change pixel at column 10 of row 2
```

and also: (this gets an other error:  "illegal memory acces")

```
MOV ESI, 0A0000H ; frame buffer address
MOV EDI, 320 * [yPosChar] + [xPosChar] ; add the appropriate offset
MOV AL, 10 ; index in the colour palette
MOV [EDI], AL ; change pixel at column 10 of row 2
```

PLEASE HELP? IDK WHAT IM DOING WRONG AND IT DRIVES ME CRAZY

Comment: It's unclear what you want the first one to do. The second one does make sense, but unfortunately the cpu does not support that addressing. You will have to calculate `320* [yPosChar]` yourself using multiplication then add the `[xPosChar]`. PS: consult relevant manuals about available addressing modes. PPS: your variables aren't even called `xPosChar` and `yPosChar`. Also be careful with operand sizes.

Comment: I still get the error "Illegal memory acces".

        MOV ESI, 0A0000H ; frame buffer address
 IMUL EDI, 320 * [yPosChar]
 ADD EDI, EDI  + [xPosChar] 
 MOV AL, 10 ; index in the colour palette
 MOV [EDI], AL ; change pixel at column 10 of row 2

Comment: the prof used ADD EDI, 320 * 2 +10 , which worked immediately, i've accidently written MOV edi... in this post, but this doesn't deny the fact that i still get the same error

Comment: Constant arithmetic works, because those are calculated by the assembler. You got the syntax of `IMUL` wrong, consult an instruction set reference. If you write the instruction you no longer need the operator. Also, as I said, be careful with operand sizes. I would change `dw` to `dd` and then you could do `mov edi, [yPosChar]; imul edi, edi, 320; add edi, [xPosChar]; mov byte [0A0000h+edi], 10`

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what your code does or doesn't contain.  Please create and post a [mcve].