# Drawing a sprite in assembly 80386

Tags: assembly, x86

Okay so, i got an example from my prof on how to create a sprite in 80386:

```
logo DW 8, 8
     DB 0FH, 00H, 00H, 0EH, 0EH, 27H, 27H, 0FH
     DB 22H, 22H, 22H, 22H, 22H, 22H, 22H, 22H
     DB 22H, 22H, 0FH, 0FH, 0FH, 0FH, 22H, 22H
     DB 22H, 22H, 0FH, 0FH, 0FH, 0FH, 22H, 22H
     DB 22H, 22H, 0FH, 0FH, 0FH, 0FH, 22H, 22H
     DB 22H, 22H, 0FH, 0FH, 0FH, 0FH, 22H, 22H
     DB 0FH, 22H, 22H, 0FH, 0FH, 22H, 22H, 0FH
     DB 0FH, 0FH, 22H, 22H, 22H, 22H, 0FH, 0FH
     DB 0FH, 0FH, 0FH, 22H, 22H, 0FH, 0FH, 0FH
```

My question is, how can i use this?
In other words, what code do i have to write to acces this "logo".
I first have to put the video mode which is:

```
mov ah, 0
mov al, 13h
int 10h
```

What do i need  to do next??

Please help, there is like no one on internet using 80386.

Comment: 80386 aka x86 is one of the most common instruction set architectures out there and likely the most common one asked about on this site.  Read up on Mode 13h and you should be able to solve this easily.  Here's a [quick introduction](http://jlp.freeservers.com/mode13h/).

Comment: The things i found are all for different processors (mostly 16bit). I work on a 32 bit processor.

Comment: Yes, the 80386 is a 32 bit processor.  It does however support all instructions and operating modes of its predecessors, the 8086 and 80286 as well.  In real mode, which is the mode you write DOS programs or boot loaders in, it behaves pretty much like the 16 bit processor the 8086 or 80286 are.  These 16 bit guides you found are perfectly applicable to the 80386.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in your *logo* are WIDTH, HEIGHT, and a bunch of COLORS (1 byte per dot).
Incidentally the HEIGHT is 9 instead of 8, or else you've got an excess data line!

Because the video mode involved is mode 13h that has a 320x200 256-colors resolution, drawing the sprite is a matter of transferring these color bytes to the video RAM.

You are going for [80386](/questions/tagged/80386) and can use the immediate operand version of the `imul` instruction. Below code draws the sprite near the center of the screen:

```
  mov  bx, 156       ; X=156
  mov  ax, 96        ; Y=96
  ...
  imul di, ax, 320   ; Y * 320
  add  di, bx        ; Y * 320 + X
  mov  ax, 0A000h    ; Video RAM
  mov  es, ax
  mov  si, logo
  cld
  lodsw
  mov  cx, ax        ; Width
  lodsw
  mov  dx, ax        ; Height
  mov  ax, 320
  sub  ax, cx        ; Offset to next line
more:
  push cx
  rep  movsb
  pop  cx
  add  di, ax
  dec  dx
  jnz  more
```

---

Looking at [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64830004/cant-add-relative-quantities-assembly-error), you could also be interested in next version:

```
xpos dw 156
ypos dw 96

  movzx ebx, word [xpos]    ; X
  movzx eax, word [ypos]    ; Y
  ...
  imul  edi, eax, 320        ; Y * 320
  add   edi, ebx             ; Y * 320 + X
  add   edi, 000A0000h       ; Video RAM (assuming ES==0)
  mov   esi, logo
  cld
  lodsw
  movzx ecx, ax              ; Width
  lodsw
  movzx edx, ax              ; Height
  mov   eax, 320
  sub   eax, ecx             ; Offset to next line
more:
  push  ecx
  rep   movsb
  pop   ecx
  add   edi, eax
  dec   edx
  jnz   more
```

Comment: The ... in your codes means there should be something there, right?For some reason, both of the codes dont work for me..

Comment: When  I run the first code i get error 0000A000. The second code doesn't even run, it gets errors with the pointers of xpos and ypos. @SepRoland

Comment: @Randomguy What I have shown to you in my answer, is the part that actually draws the sprite on the screen 13h. You need to write yourself the program where you insert my code. I can't possibly know your programming environment or the assembler program that you use. An error like "0000A000" doesn't make sense to me! It could mean anything. What you should do is post another question with your newest program, based on what I answered of course. I, or someone else, will take a look at that for sure.